# Using the new value of a dynamic vue input

Tags: vue.js

I am retrieving an object of objects, for each object I am making a list of text inputs to edit their values. My problem is that the value of the input is not changing so it only submits with the starting value, how can I make the input value dynamic?

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="variable in variables">
        <input type="text" :value="variable.value" />
        <button @click="updateVariable(variable.id, variable.value)">Update</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

...

```
methods: {
    updateVariable(id, value) {
        axios.post('/destination', {
                params: {
                    id: id,
                    value: value
                }
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `v-model`, `:value` won't track the change

```js
// Fake axios to debug with
const axios = {
  post(ep = "", data) {
    console.log(`would send \n${JSON.stringify(data)}\nto ${ep}`);
    return Promise.resolve("OK");
  }
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      variables: {
        foo: {
          id: "foo",
          value: "bar"
        },
        fizz: {
          id: "fizz",
          value: "buzz"
        }
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateVariable(id, value) {
      axios.post('/destination', {
          params: {
            id: id,
            value: value
          }
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="variable in variables">
      <input type="text" v-model="variable.value" />
      <button @click="updateVariable(variable.id, variable.value)">Update</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That works perfectly... I thought :value was just the short hand of v-model lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are just giving an initial value to each input, but you're not binding it to any reactive data attribute.

Use the [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) directive to use input bindings and apply Vue's reactivity to the input:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="variable in variables">
        <input type="text" v-model="variable.value" />
        <button @click="updateVariable(variable.id, variable.value)">Update</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please note that the `variables` array must be declared inside your component's [data object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) for this to work properly.

Comment: That works perfectly... I thought :value was just the short hand of v-model lol. Thank you.